# How to stretch background image of a table cell with CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, background, css-tables

How can I stretch background image of a table cell with CSS? I have Googled it with no results.

When you set background image of a cell and the background size is smaller than the cell, then it will be repeated.

How can I force this background to stretch the entire table cell instead?

Comment: The accepted answer to the question is no longer correct - all current major browsers support stretching through CSS now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't stretch a background image.

If you want to stretch an image, you have to put it in an `img` tag. You can use absolute positioning to put content on top of the image.

Comment: but i made this thread for tables / absolute position not ok for background image of tables / any other idea ?

Comment: @LostLord: No, you simply can't stretch a background image, unless you want to wait until CSS 3 compatible browsers is a lot more common.

Comment: There are also javascript libraries that do what it's described on this answer :)

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to [stretch a background image using the `background-size` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Examples:

```
body { background-size: 100% auto } /* Stretches image to full horiz. width */
body { background-size: 50% 50% } /* Stretches image to half of available
width and height - WARNING: aspect ratio not maintained */

body { background-size: cover } /* Ensures that image covers full area */
body { background-size: contain } /* Ensures that image is completely visible */
```

All major current browsers support the feature:

- IE since 9.0
- Chrome since 3.0
- Firefox since 4.0
- Opera since 10.0
- Safari since 4.1

Comment: backgroung size is very very limited / any other idea ?

Comment: @LostLord not really, not without complicated jQuery workarounds. What  do you need to do?

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. Care to fix it, please?

Comment: @MoonLight You're limited! ;-)
Sorry. Your comment is old. Now support is pretty good and background-size is a life saver.

Comment: @ArmelLarcier there are a lot internet users with old browsers... even in 2016... do you know why? because i (myself) still have windows xp 3. with its browsers... i have IE7... I don't like to upgrade... i think windows 7 and 8 and ... are not good... in my opinion a software is great at first... but after upgrading... they'll add extra codes to them that i don't like... for example: check the notepad in windows xp and check it in the windows 7... If you are professional and a programmer... you'll know why i didn't upgrade...

Comment: @MahdiJazini All true especially if your app/website gets shipped worldwide. Aside from that, if your a pro programmer on xp and you're using Notepad by choice, you have to love suffering right?

Comment: @ArmelLarcier :)) i have Notepad++ ... Actually notepad was an example to describe upgraded programs usually add unnecessary options. here photoshop 7 can resolve all my problems. why should i upgrade it? i like old sandwiches :D easy and fast to eat...  ;)

Comment: @MahdiJazini I follow the same philosophy with Apple software and I get teased all the time so I felt i ought to give that back ;)

Comment: @ArmelLarcier Today i have logged into in one of my weblogs and get a report. it's for 2016. you can easily see IE7 at the top after the firefox also you can see IE 5 and IE 6. 91 visit for firefox and 59 visits for IE7 and 6 visits for IE6 and 5 visits for IE5 http://s3.img7.ir/w6C1L.png

Answer (score 3):

It is possible.

**NOTE: This is using CSS3 and will not be supported by inferior browsers.**

If you set your cell with this styling it should solve your problem. It will also allow for collapsible tables too because you're using %.

```
background-image: url('XXX');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```